# Who were the Red Warriors in The Solar War

Tags: warhammer-40k, horus-heresy, siege-of-terra

In the Solar War (of the Horus Heresy series) the mining ship that Mersadie Oliton was on was attacked by "Red Armoured" space marines. However, are they Word Bearers or Blood Angels?

Given that

> Mersadie is carrying a deamon to the Phalanx and that said deamon massacres the boarders it seems unlikely that it's the 17th legion.

However, I would have expected her to comment if she was being attacked by loyalist marines.

Which legion attacked Mersadie's ship?

Answer (score 1):

The ship was attacked by Traitor Forces, however the warriors that attack Mersadie Oliton and the other prisoners are not space marines but in fact the prison guards instructed to execute all prisoners rather then see them fall into enemy hands.

The identity of the traitor forces that attack the ship is never made clear, it may be that it was non astartes traitor forces. Or forces send by Maloghurst with the aim of freeing Oliton to complete her mission.